# How to create a transition where a fragment is slid upwards over another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

I have two fragments named `MainFragment` and `PlaybackFragment` respectively. I use the Navigation Architecture Component to implement navigation between the two.

What I want to do is create a transition where `PlaybackFragment` would be slid over `MainFragment`, and when the user closes `PlaybackFragment`, it would slide down, revealing `MainFragment` again.

To do this, I created two translation animations. One for sliding up:

```
anim_nav_slide_up.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

And one for sliding down:

```
anim_nav_slide_down.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

The problem is that instead of `MainFragment` remaining stationary while the transition occurs, `MainFragment` insteadd slides downwards as `PlaybackFragment` is shown, with it sliding upwards when `PlaybackFragment` is closed. Ive attached an example below.

[image: Notice how MainFragment slides downwards as PlaybackFragment slides upwards]

Is there a way to make `PlaybackFragment` slide over `MainFragment` without `MainFragment` moving? I don't want to use Bottom Sheets, as I don't think that's their intended purpose in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an animation that does nothing.

hold.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0.0%p"
        android:toYDelta="0.0%p" />
</set>
```

and in navigation component xml file assign it as `popEnterAnim`

```
app:popEnterAnim="@anim/hold"
app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_down"
```